# No schema found for the org.eclipse.wst.server.core.serverTypes extension point

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to create a new server type plugin programmatically and after re-search I found that I need to use `org.eclipse.wst.server.core.serverTypes` extension point, but when I try to add above extension point in eclipse juno sdk, I am getting "No schema found..." error . Can anyone please guide me why I am getting above error? Am I missing any required dependencies here?

FYI, I have added `org.eclipse.wst.server.core` and `org.eclipse.wst.server.ui` as an dependencies but still no luck and Googling leads to resources for other extension points but not for this. Any guidance is highly appreciated.

BTW, I am using SDK Version of Eclipse Juno

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I am able to find answer my self, in-order to make this work, we need to install WTP SDK installed on Eclipse. This can be done using `Help -> Install New Software...` and providing URL: http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/repository/juno/ . This solves no schema found issue.